# Terminal that supports the ANSI italic escape code?

Tags: linux, terminal, gnome-terminal, ansi

I would like to replace GVim with Vim in the terminal. One of the nice things about GVim is that it is able to display text using italics.

Vim allows setting an ANSI escape code for italics (`\e[3m`), but this does not work in Gnome Terminal. Is there a terminal emulator that supports the ANSI escape code for italics?

Comment: Are you certain that this is an official ANSI escape code?

Comment: No, I'm not :) Some sources mention it as a valid code though, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: That Wikipedia page shows `\e[3m` (3 rather than 2) which agrees with `tput -T rxvt-unicode sitm|hexdump -C`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've tested a number of terminal emulators with `echo -e "\e[3mfoo\e[23m"` as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/514524/53508). I went through the Arch wiki [list](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/List_of_applications#Terminal_emulators), testing emulators in the official repositories.

### Support italics

- konsole 15.04.3
- rxvt-unicode 9.21
- tilda 1.2.4
- xterm 318
- gnome-terminal 3.16.2
- pantheon-terminal 0.3.1.1
- yakuake 2.9.9
- roxterm 3.1.3
- sakura 3.3.0
- termite 10
- mlterm 3.3.8
- terminix 1.0.0
- terminator 1.91
- xfce4-terminal 0.8.5.1

### Do not support italics

- guake 0.7.2
- lxterminal 0.2.0
- rxvt 2.7.10
- terminology 0.8.0
- lilyterm 0.9.9.2
- mate-terminal 1.10.1
- xfce4-terminal 0.6.3
- KiTTY 0.64.0.4
- PuTTY 0.65 Beta

Comment: Note that many terminal emulators are based on the [VTE terminal emulator library](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/List_of_applications#VTE-based). vte2 (for gtk 2) is obsolete now, only those emulators based on the current vte3 implementation (e.g. gnome-terminal). For guake, gtk3 bindings and hence italics support, are targeted for [milestone 0.8.4](https://github.com/Guake/guake/milestones/0.8.4)

Comment: @kba Yes, good point. My terminal of choice, terminator, is supporting italics in the development version, which is based on vte3.

Answer (score 11):

GNOME Terminal (3.6.1) supports italics via `\e[3m`.

Answer (score 6):

[rxvt-unicode](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/rxvt-unicode.html)

Answer (score 2):

I will add some *modern* terminals.

- [Alacritty](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty) (macOS, Linux, Windows)
- [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/) (macOS)
- [kitty](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/kitty) (macOS, Linux)
- [wezterm](https://github.com/wez/wezterm) (macOS, Linux, Windows)

They all have support for italic text.