# vim txtfmt plugin " italic format not working"

Tags: xterm, vim-plugins

**[Image URL](http://img525.imageshack.us/img525/4348/txtfmt.png)**

After executing :MakeTestPage in vim

As you can see in the image ...

underline(u),bold(b),bold-underline(bu) displays correctly

but what is happening to italic(i) ? It shows white background ...

**Can anybody tell my why italic format shows white background rather than italic font?**

I am using **xterm** as terminal emulator

my $term value is **xterm-256color**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xterm` does not support an italic character attribute. You can change the appearance of a character by making it bold, underlined, reverse or colored, but not by changing its font to italic. The plugin is probably using reverse in place of italic.

Comment: thanks, it means xterm is a problem. So can you tell, the names of terminal that support italic char or is there any way italic char can be supported in xterm.

Comment: According to the answer to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/204743/terminal-that-supports-ansi-italic-escape-code), [rxvt-unicode](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/rxvt-unicode.html) does. You could also use gvim instead of terminal vim.

Comment: Note: xterm supports italic just fine for xft rendered TrueType fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Support for italic varies across terminals. Xterm doesn't support it, but (e.g.) rxvt-unicode terminal does. The Txtfmt plugin always specifies "italic" in the Vim syntax definition, but a terminal that doesn't support italic may use reverse or something similar... Here's a thread that touches on this...

http://www.mail-archive.com/vim_use@googlegroups.com/msg06341.html